# Buildx error when deploying models in Nuclio(CVAT)

Tags: docker, wsl-2, buildx, cvat

So when i try to build models in nuclio using the web-gui i get the error log

```
stderr:
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/
```

I am using docker desktop, and have wsl integration enabled...i have buildx installed and working in both windows and wsl.

[Buildx in WSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll4BJ.png)
[Buildx in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xaGw.png)

I am using docker desktop, and have wsl integration enabled

another thing i have done is moved my docker-desktop-data wsl image to my second drive by
exporting-unregistering-importing

Note:  I have hosted both cvat and Nuclio on my local machine using the serverless tutorial available on the [CVAT manual](https://opencv.github.io/cvat/docs/manual/advanced/serverless-tutorial/)

i have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling docker desktop,
also tried manually adding buildx file in cli-pligin folders and remaking the images after making sure buildx is working